# Add shadow and depth to a android toolbar

Tags: android, xamarin.android, shadow

I am trying to create a music player in Xamarin Android. I have a toolbar at the bottom of the layout and I am trying to add a nice shadow and depth looking like in this picture: [image]

This is my layout:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/IDFIRSTTOOLBAR"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#543011"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/IDVIEWPAGER"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#ffffff">
        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/IDPAGERTABSTRIP"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/IDSECONDTOOLBAR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:color="#000000"
        android:background="#e2e2e2" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is that an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What is your *specific* question?

Comment: I tryied the elevation attribute introduced in Android Lolipop but it didn't work  and beside this, my project is intended for devices that runs versions of android below Lolipop. I also tryied to create my own styles but I couldn't get the effect I wantet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tryied the elevation attribute introduced in Android Lolipop but it didn't work and beside this, my project is intended for devices that runs versions of android below Lolipop.

Since elevation attribute is not available, you can try to use `shape` to create a shadow style and apply this style use `android:background` attribute of your `Toolbar`.

For the using of `shape` in a xamarin android project, you can refer to this blog: [Android Tricks: Using Shape for Theming](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tricks-using-shape-for-theming/).

Or you can also try to use [Layer List](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) to create your background resources.

I've tested to define a shape like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
     android:angle="90"
     android:endColor="#88444444" />
</shape>
```

And apply it in a button, it works on android 4.4 emulator.